# How far away could one be and still see the atom bomb explosions?

Tags: nuclear-weapons

In the film *Empire of the Sun* (1987), the Nagasaki atom bomb explosion is depicted as being visible (albeit faintly) from Shanghai. Would that really have been possible? According to Google, the two cities are about 810 km apart.

Update: I've uploaded the clip from the movie to [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L4HWrKafoSI).

Comment: @DavidRicherby: When reading the title of this question in the hot questions list, I at first assumed this was a question from [Worldbuilding SE](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/). Interestingly, based on that misconception, I found it completely natural that there might be other kinds of seeing available ;)

Comment: Are you looking for the explosion (the flash), or the characteristic mushroom cloud?

Comment: In theory an inversion layer, or several, might allow bending of the flash of the explosion around the horizon.  Probably not the explanation here.

Comment: Related: [Was the atomic bombing of Nagasaki visible from Shanghai, as in the film “Empire of the Sun”?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/55621/49)

Comment: Answered [here](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/55635/20680)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is not possible. And this has nothing to do with the actual brightness
of explosion. A similar explosion on the Moon will probably be visible from the earth if the weather conditions are good and if you know when and where to look.

According to the Wikipedia, the Nagasaki bomb was exploded at the height of 503 m, about 1/2 km.
To be directly visible from 810 km distance it had to be exploded at the height
more than 60 km.

(Calculation: 810 km=437 nautical miles=7.289 degrees. The radius of Earth is 6370 km; 6370/cos 7.289=6423. Subtract 6370, we get 63 km. This is the height at which the bomb had to be exploded to be visible at 810 km. I neglected refraction but the difference between 60 km and 0.5 km is so large that refraction can be neglected.)

Of course there are described cases of strong anomalous refraction, but they usually occur in polar regions http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Novaya_Zemlya_effect,
and one does not expect it on the latitude of Japan.

EDIT. A suggestion in a comment was that a reflection from a cloud could be seen. 
Again, the information found in Wikipedia shows that clouds do not reach such heights, except in polar regions (stratospheric clouds). In addition to this, a reflection would be much weaker than the original flash, and perhaps cannot be seen at 800 km.

EDIT2. I am surprised by the number of comments to this answer. Nobody would discuss the question whether the Great Fire of London could be visible from Switzerland (about the same distance), because of some super-unusual refraction or some super-high clouds, or whatever. The only difference is that a nuclear explosion involves a very bright (and very short) flash. But this difference is irrelevant.

Comment: My first reaction on seeing this question was to suggest it be moved to a math or physics stack to raise the odds of someone being able to provide this exact calculation. Good job.

Comment: ...technically I guess it doesn't answer the (slightly different) question in the title though. Based on the [very rough formula here](http://www-rohan.sdsu.edu/~aty/explain/atmos_refr/horizon.html), I came up with a bit less than 54 miles (86km) as the furthest it could be seen over the horizon.

Comment: One could perhaps see the light reflected from clouds at a higher elevation.

Comment: When you fly an airplane at 10 km altotude, do you ever see clouds ABOVE you?

Comment: I believe you are off by up to a factor of 2, because you have neglected the altitude of the observer.. To a first approximation the **combined height of observer and observation** must equal the amount you calculated. However, Shanghai being at sea level yields an observer altitude of essentially zero.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Nowhere on the surface of the earth is more than 9km above sea level, which is nothing like the the 60km required.

Comment: @Alex: Actually, yes; wispy cirrus clouds can exist at much higher altitudes than even planes commercial transports fly, up to 60,000 feet or higher.

Comment: @Alex: Unfortunately, I can't fly my plane at anywhere near that altitude (its ceiling is about 15K ft).  However, per Wikipedia cumulonimbus clouds (thunderheads) can reach altitudes of 75K ft/23K m: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulonimbus_cloud#Appearance  Also consider the case of high-altitude clouds midway between the explosion and viewing point.

Comment: Why don't you simply suggest that the light was reflected from a UFO which was passing by?

Comment: @Alex Yes, I frequently see clouds above me when flying around at FL300-FL400. Not usually cumulus clouds, mind you, but definitely cirrus clouds. Also, I've seen lots of thunderstorms that had tops well above our airliner's cruising altitude. Additionally, while fat man detonated at 500 m, its fireball reached around 6,000 m. Given that cirrus clouds can be seen for ~250 miles, it's quite conceivable for the flash to have reflected on cirrus clouds about halfway between the blast and Shanghai and for those same clouds to have been observable from Shanghai, especially with no terrain there.

Comment: @Alex: I don't consider UFOs because a) I've never seen one; and b) one probably wouldn't be big enough to reflect much light.  I have seen clouds at high altitudes, and have seen lightning in clouds roughly 200 miles from me, from about 9500 ft altitude.  (Me crossing California's Central Valley around Sacramento, storms located about 100 miles east of Reno.

Comment: This answer is dubious at best imho. Refraction can make visible light travel [hundreds of miles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horizon) in the right conditions, and even further in the case of radio waves. This property was used to set up transatlantic radio-telegraphs in the opening years of the 20th century.

Comment: I challenge you to give a single historic example of refraction (of usual light) which makes visible an object 800 km away, and not in polar regions.

Comment: @Alex: But we have very few instances of atomic weapons being detonated above ground, which is what applies here.  Since experimental evidence trumps theory, why not search for other accounts from people who were in a position to observe?

Comment: You do not need nuclear explosions to investigate refraction in the atmosphere. Either refraction permits to to see objects 800 km away or not. Nuclear explosion, especially over land is not going to change the properties of refraction.

Comment: @Alex: We are not necessarily talking about refraction here.  We are talking about people who claim to have seen nuclear explosions at large distances.  Now either they did see the explosions - in which case there must be some mechanism - or they are lying.  So if there are many unrelated accounts alleging this, either we need to find a mechanism, or we need to figure out why they're all lying.

Comment: "Lying" and "telling something which is not true" is not exactly the same, and I leave it to the others to discuss why people are telling this. (There can be several plausible explanations). My point was only to explain why it is physically impossible.

Comment: @Alex: Once again, observation trumps theory.  Especially ironic here, as if you'd asked a physicist about splitting the atom a century ago, they would have said "physically impossible".

Comment: "Observations" by the personages of a sci-fi movie? I don't see any point in continuing this "discussion".

Answer (score 12):

The [link provided by @T.E.D.](http://www-rohan.sdsu.edu/%7Eaty/explain/atmos_refr/horizon.html) combined with the [observations of Major Charles Sweeney](http://www.mphpa.org/classic/COLLECTIONS/CG-JPAP/Pages-2/CGP-JPAP-115.htm) that the height of the flash, off the cirrus clouds over Nagasaki, was "at least 6 miles (or 31,000 feet) [above the explosion]" giving a *refraction-free visibility* for such a reflected flash as about 230 miles or 370 km.

> The underside of the great clouds over Nagasaki was amber-tinted, as though reflecting the conflagaration at least 6 miles below. Beneath the top cloud mass, white in colour, there gradually climbed a turbulent pillar of black smoke and dust which emitted a second fireball less vivid than the first.

```
distance in miles =~ sqrt( 7 * height-in-feet / 4) = sqrt(7 * 31,000 / 4)  
                  =~ 230 miles ~ 380 km
```

However, as noted further down in [the link provided by T.E.D.](http://www-rohan.sdsu.edu/%7Eaty/explain/atmos_refr/horizon.html):

> Unfortunately, the refraction varies considerably from day to day, and
> from one place to another. It is particularly variable over water:
> because of the high heat capacity of water, the air is nearly always
> at a different temperature from that of the water, so there is a
> thermal boundary layer, in which the temperature gradient is far from
> uniform.
>
> ...
>
> In conditions that produce superior mirages, there are inversion layers in which the ray curvature exceeds that of the Earth. Then, in principle, you can see infinitely far — there really is no horizon.
>
> ...
>
> However, there is one situation in which objects can be made out at great distances: when they are silhouetted against a bright background, such as the setting Sun, or (just after sunset) a bright twilit sky.
>
> ...
>
> What's the record for visibility without help from the silhouetting effect? I think that might belong to the report of the expedition led by Korzenewsky (1923), who reported seeing snow-capped peaks of a mountain range 750 km away. Conditions were perfect: the lower atmosphere was in shadow at sunset; the peaks were quite high (4650 meters, or over 15,000 feet); they were covered with white snow, increasing their visibility; and there must also have been considerable looming to bring these distant features above the observers' horizon.

This observation by Korzenewsky is very similar in circumstances to the reported sighting from Shanghai, so I would not rule it out completely without further investigation of the meteorological conditions that day. It was late summer, with clear calm conditions (breeze < 5 mph at ground zero), which is typical of mirage conditions.

[This link](http://www.islandnet.com/%7Esee/weather/elements/supmrge.htm) goes into the detailed meteorological conditions necessary for a long-distance *superior mirage*, such as the reported observation must have been. The required *temperature inversion* could easily have existed in late morning in early August over the cooler waters of the Sea of Japan.

**Update**:
Sweeney can accurately say that "the underside of the great clouds over Nagasaki" were at least 6 miles high, because he himself was at 30,000 feet for the bombing run and aftermath.

Answer (score 4):

Note that the atomic cloud after the explosion is said to have reached a height of 70,000 feet (about 21 km). Although this still appears to be too low, with refraction and other effects, it might have been possible to see it from Shanghai.

Comment: This answer is the only one on the right track.

Comment: @Potatoswatter - Agreed. The only thing missing from it is that [atmospheric refraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmospheric_refraction) can make visible light travel [hundreds of miles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horizon) in the right conditions.

Answer (score 0):

With Earth curvature in mind, 810km gives a 50km high curve.
So the earth is flat or the clip in the movie is full of crap. On the other hand, after doing some research, they state nuke explosions can be seen from 600 miles distance, but 600 miles gives a curve of 71km, I don't think we can see a plume, unless the earth is flat.

Curve calculator here http://dizzib.github.io/earth/curve-calc/index.html

Comment: You have ignored the mirage and refraction effects that have commonly been noted in these examples.